# Is an SSD good for programming?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I just recently installed a 240 GB SSD replacing a 250 HD and I have loved the speed increase so far.  But, there is something bothering me somewhat.  I understand how SSDs have a limited life due to how many times it can be rewritten.  This seems contrary to being useful for programming, especially if an IDE saves a program every time it is executed or as a fail safe every few minutes.  At least that is what I'm assuming happens with Eclipse and Java.  It just makes me wonder how long the SSD will last.  Even if the IDE saves the program every ten minutes for about 8 hours a day, it will probably take years for that section to become unreadable, right?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80864/what-not-to-put-on-an-ssd

Comment: A memory cell in a SSD does not become unreadable after reaching its maximum amount of writes.  Where did you hear that was the case?

Comment: I should have added that even though a section is unwritable (is that a word), it is still readable.  I'm just looking at the bigger picture.  Is the wear generally considered insignificant?

Comment: Wear leveling prevents individual sectors from wearing out prematurely. It really comes down to what the write endurance is of your SSD as a whole. I'd say your usage pattern is actually relatively light, and modern SSDs generally exceed their rated write endurance by a lot anyway. If you're worried about it you can check the S.M.A.R.T. data as @Snowman said every once in a while, but I wouldn't sweat it if I were you

Answer (score 10):

There are two concerns here.

> Even if the IDE saves the program every ten minutes for about 8 hours a day, it will probably take years for that section to become unreadable, right?

SSDs use [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling). This ensures that a single section of the drive's memory bank does not become unusable long before another section *due to normal use* (as opposed to a manufacturing defect).

This means that while heavy usage might cause the entire drive to wear out sooner, it will not wear out any particular part of the drive faster.

> I understand how SSDs have a limited life due to how many times it can be rewritten. This seems contrary to being useful for programming, especially if an IDE saves a program every time it is executed or as a fail safe every few minutes.

A modern IDE and compiler will make many small reads and writes to a drive:

- Programming non-trivial projects involves loading and saving many source files.
- Compiling involves reading each source file, possibly writing temporary files, and certainly the compiled and linked result.
- Modern IDEs such as Eclipse and Visual Studio are very complex pieces of software with many components and plugins. More than many other types of software, IDEs may involve reading and writing a large amount of metadata and cached data. For example, look in the `.metadata` directory inside any Eclipse workspace. Some versions of some source control plugins may have a very large amount of extra files.

Your concerns about wearing out an SSD due to using an IDE are worth looking at due to these facts. However, I would not be too concerned about it:

- Newer SSDs have a very long life. I have read multiple articles on this: a quick search brings up [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2856052/grueling-endurance-test-blows-away-ssd-durability-fears.html) which corroborates many others that I have read.
- SSDs use [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) just like HDDs do. If you monitor your drive using one of several tools ([GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/) is a good cross-platform tool for this) you can detect most problems before they occur.

On top of the objective analysis, I can tell you that I have dual SSDs and I program using both Eclipse and Visual Studio. I have been using these drives for over two years, and SMART reports that I am nowhere close to needing to be concerned about wearing out either drive.

Comment: Note that while the endurance test is an interesting experiment, don't expect any usable life past the rated lifetime. Typically, as the NAND wears out it doesn't fail immediately. Rather, it can no longer retain your data for as long, so old data (not written recently) could potentially be lost. That said, even the rated lifetime of modern SSDs is long enough that IDE writes are negligible over their expected lifetime - and you normally need to worry about sudden controller failure before NAND wearout, so keep making those backups!

Comment: Hi, this answer is about 2 years old now. What are your opinions now on this question ? Did you still recommend buying an SSD ? What another problems you faced after a long time usage in case of SSD ? Thanks!!

Comment: @Shivam nothing has changed in the two years since I wrote this answer. I still highly recommend SSDs, just monitor drive health and take backups as with any other drive.

Comment: On my current development machine, I use around 800GB of my hard disk. If you use SSD, you probably end up buying up to 500GB as that is the most economic price range as of 2019. I partitioned my C drive too small (200GB) and it is close to the edge (after some fiddling with moving ``%USER" to second parition). Just by having a few programming languages installed (VS2019, Haskell, Julia, Rust). All my sources and compiles etc I do on my second partition. I cannot see how SSD can not be a limiting factor as for capacity required.